# retrieve Mysql server time using ADO.net

Tags: mysql, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I am using ADO.net and LINQ-to-Entities in VS2010 to connect to Mysql server, and I would like to know what is the current date and time on the server side.

Is there any method to do this using a LINQ query?
I don't want to use any SQL statements in my program.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a stored procedure in MySql (assuming  you have v5 or greater) and creating a function in your EF class that calls it?